# What's the difference between "mod_fastcgi" and "mod_fcgid"?

Tags: apache-http-server, fastcgi

I'm writing a fast CGI application to use with my Apache 2.2 (prefork) on Ubuntu Linux.

I need to choose between `mod_fastcgi` and `mod_fcgid`, but I can't find any resource that documents the difference (if any) to help me decide which one to enable with Apache.

Any one knows what the differences/pro/cons of using `mod_fastcgi` / `mod_fcgid` is/are?

Comment: It seems to be mostly licensing but DreamHost says there are some performance considerations, too: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Mod_fcgid

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's mostly licencing differences. `mod_fcgid` is the free variant of `mod_fastcgi`.

The way of configuration also slightly differs. Besides that, `mod_fastcgi` is slightly faster.

Answer (score 31):

The difference is explained quite well here:
[libapache2-mod-fastcgi: fastcgi does not retry select() on EAGAIN](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=504132#25)

**In short:** `mod_fcgid` passes just one request to the FCGI server at a time while `mod_fastcgi` passes several requests at once, the latter is usually better for PHP, as PHP can manage several request using several threads and opcode caches like APC usually work only with threads and not with processes. This means that using `mod_fcgid` you end up having many PHP processes which all have their very own opcode cache.

This is also mentioned in the documentation of `mod_fcgid` under [Special PHP considerations](https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#examples).

Comment: It should be preferred answer